# How change the Y position of moving forward spaceship in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, smoothing

i have start a project in unity 3d.I want to make a spaceship that moving forward,but when i pressed the ArrowUp then i want to change its y postion to 
( currentpos+ 1.5 ) but i want this smoothly.
this is my code

```
transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10f;

if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow))
transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, 5f, 
transform.position.z);
```

through the above code the Y position of object can b changed but it work so fast and i want to make it smooth.
so please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution to your problem is to use [`Mathf.SmoothDamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothDamp.html).

Example:

```
private float targetY = 0f;
private float verticalVelocity = 0f;
private const float smoothTime = 1f;

private void Update()
{
    transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10f;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        targetY = 5f;
    }

    float y = Mathf.SmoothDamp(transform.position.y, targetY, ref verticalVelocity, smoothTime);
    transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, y, transform.position.z);

}
```

This example will smoothly change the `y` coordinate to 5 over the course of 1 second (you can change the `smoothTime` constant for a different time).

Comment: Hi dear, thanks for your response.but there are some question .

Comment: but dear i have some question. 1) why you declare targetY variable and where i can use this? 2) when i run my project then my object position changed without any key press. but i want that when i press a key for long time or just press and released it then the y position should be changed smoothly :)

Comment: oh thanks dear i checked again and now it work fine  stay happy dear :)

Answer (score 1):

Based in your own code the easiest way for you to work it out could be something like this

```
//this sets the X position
transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10f;

//if the button is pressed then modify Y
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow))
    transform.position += new Vector3 (0, 5f  * Time.deltaTime * y_speed,0);
```

`y_speed` could be a `public float y_speed = 1.0f` in your script so you could modify it from the inspector to get the effect you want to achieve.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @FaisalmirzaMirza if it's working now for you, please can you check this answer as the valid one?

Comment: I have check this its work fine but mathf.smoothdamp() function is much better it works more smoothly.

Comment: Great! @FaisalmirzaMirza so give that answer the "green check!"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your spaceship is a rigidbody, you should take a look at Rigidbody.AddForce
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

By working with forces, you can get a smooth movement in all directions very easily, and tweak it within the Rigidbody's parameters (like mass) without fiddling in the script again. It's part of the Unity physics model.

If you only want to move in y-direction, input a vector like (0,1,0) but you can also input the Transform.forward vector of your spaceship's Gameobject. That way, it will always move the direction it is facing in.